# Re-open my message and Give me solution if you can

Tags: discussion, status-completed

https://askubuntu.com/questions/289391/xubuntu-13-04-mobile-broadband-can-not-be-enabled

My question was closed, I would like to see it re-open.

Comment: Your question was re-opened. Beware of words you use when commenting to other users, serious rudeness is not something we tolerate on the site. If you found a solution for your issue use the answers area on the main post instead of editing anything to the question it self.

Comment: Halo Bruno. Thank you providing another QUICK management / administrative action. Amazing ! It is below 20 minutes. It is very contrast with the question which is UNanswered after 5 days. Good work.

Comment: Trust me Bruno. I know how to be polite if people treat me politely. And thank you so much for re-opening my message. God bless you.

Comment: There might not be an answer for your issue, depends on what the community can help or not on. Your question was closed mainly because of its content and some confusion. Learn how the site works, what kind of questions you can do here and how to make your question better so it can actually be answered. The users that closed your question were only doing what needs to be done so we dont end up with a bunch of weird questions on the site that cannot be answered. Nothing personal or as a for of rudeness, sometimes there is just not enough time to follow closely everything we find. Apologies.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Bruno. I do understand their position. I just hope that they understand my situation too. I am doing something like trouble-shooting by myself; alone. At least, before closing my message, they talk to me and give me time while I am trying to understand the problem. Well, Ubuntu is for humans and humans communicate, right? I use Windows7 but I want to use a Linux variant as well, so that I will not depend on one platform only. Again, thanks for talking.

Comment: We are all just humans, don't sweat about it, its fine. Have a good day and anything we can do further let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Question has been re-open and edited. Seems clean now. Comments removed.